# Why is this Ruby Squeel (PostgreSQL) call returning nil, when it's clearly not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, squeel

I have a search page that allows a user to search for athletes based on criteria such as GPA and sport stats. When only one search filter is used, the PostgreSQL returns the correct answer. When more than one search filter is used, it will work ONLY if the same stat is being used in both search filters. For instance, if I do a search of "GPA > 3" and "GPA == 4" it will return the corresponding athlete. If I do "GPA > 3" and "ACT > 20" (both of which are true on the same athlete), it returns nothing (empty array).

For reference throughout this page, here is what @conditions looks like (it's transformed into an array in the code rather than a hash so the loop can iterate, but you get the gist):

```
{
"0"=>{"category"=>"1", "stat_type_id"=>"22", "predicate"=>"Greater Than", 
"q"=>"2", "type"=>"stat"}, 

"1"=>{"category"=>"1", "stat_type_id"=>"2", 
"predicate"=>"Greater Than", "q"=>"10", "type"=>"stat"}
}
```

Below is the code (Squeel syntax):

```
def query
  relation = Athlete.listed.for_sport( self.sport )

  return relation if @conditions.blank?

  @conditions = @conditions.map { |k, v| v } if @conditions.is_a?(Hash)

  debugger

  @conditions.each do |condition|
    case condition[:type]
    when "stat"
      if !condition[:q].eql?("")
        relation = case condition[:predicate]
        when /less than/i
          relation.joins{stats}.where{(stats.stat_type_id.eq condition[:stat_type_id]) & (stats.value.lt (StatType.where(:id => condition[:stat_type_id]).first.display_as_decimal == true ? condition[:q].to_f.to_s : condition[:q].to_i.to_s))}
        when /greater than/i
          relation.joins{stats}.where{(stats.stat_type_id.eq condition[:stat_type_id]) & (stats.value.gt (StatType.where(:id => condition[:stat_type_id]).first.display_as_decimal == true ? condition[:q].to_f.to_s : condition[:q].to_i.to_s))}
        when /equal to/i
          relation.joins{stats}.where{(stats.stat_type_id.eq condition[:stat_type_id]) & (stats.value.eq (StatType.where(:id => condition[:stat_type_id]).first.display_as_decimal == true ? condition[:q].to_f.to_s : condition[:q].to_i.to_s))}
        when /not equal to/i
          relation.joins{stats}.where{(stats.stat_type_id.eq condition[:stat_type_id]) & (stats.value.not_eq (StatType.where(:id => condition[:stat_type_id]).first.display_as_decimal == true ? condition[:q].to_f.to_s : condition[:q].to_i.to_s))}
        end
      end
    when "academic"
      relation
    when "social"
      relation
    end
  end

  relation
end
```

I have included below two PostgreSQL calls grabbed from ruby-debug (I'm using Squeel, a Ruby wrapper for PostgreSQL). If you scroll down in both calls, you'll see that the first and second calls are identical, but the second has an extra AND (and follows the same format as the first, should work fine).

Call 1 (one parameter):

```
SELECT "users"."id"                                  AS t0_r0,
       "users"."name"                                AS t0_r1,
       "users"."first_name"                          AS t0_r2,
       "users"."last_name"                           AS t0_r3,
       "users"."facebook_id"                         AS t0_r4,
       "users"."access_token"                        AS t0_r5,
       "users"."birthday"                            AS t0_r6,
       "users"."gender"                              AS t0_r7,
       "users"."device_token"                        AS t0_r8,
       "users"."current_city"                        AS t0_r9,
       "users"."hometown"                            AS t0_r10,
       "users"."relationship_status"                 AS t0_r11,
       "users"."avatar_file_name"                    AS t0_r12,
       "users"."avatar_content_type"                 AS t0_r13,
       "users"."avatar_file_size"                    AS t0_r14,
       "users"."avatar_updated_at"                   AS t0_r15,
       "users"."email"                               AS t0_r16,
       "users"."encrypted_password"                  AS t0_r17,
       "users"."reset_password_token"                AS t0_r18,
       "users"."reset_password_sent_at"              AS t0_r19,
       "users"."remember_created_at"                 AS t0_r20,
       "users"."sign_in_count"                       AS t0_r21,
       "users"."current_sign_in_at"                  AS t0_r22,
       "users"."last_sign_in_at"                     AS t0_r23,
       "users"."current_sign_in_ip"                  AS t0_r24,
       "users"."last_sign_in_ip"                     AS t0_r25,
       "users"."authentication_token"                AS t0_r26,
       "users"."created_at"                          AS t0_r27,
       "users"."updated_at"                          AS t0_r28,
       "users"."time_zone"                           AS t0_r29,
       "users"."username"                            AS t0_r30,
       "users"."middle_name"                         AS t0_r31,
       "users"."primary_sport_id"                    AS t0_r32,
       "users"."state"                               AS t0_r33,
       "users"."high_school"                         AS t0_r34,
       "users"."phone"                               AS t0_r35,
       "users"."user_type_id"                        AS t0_r36,
       "users"."agreed_to_terms_and_conditions"      AS t0_r37,
       "users"."agreed_to_information_integrity"     AS t0_r38,
       "users"."agreed_to_content_responsibility"    AS t0_r39,
       "users"."account_type_id"                     AS t0_r40,
       "users"."social_score"                        AS t0_r41,
       "users"."recruit_year"                        AS t0_r42,
       "users"."college_major"                       AS t0_r43,
       "users"."secondary_sport_id"                  AS t0_r44,
       "users"."handedness"                          AS t0_r45,
       "users"."checkdin_id"                         AS t0_r46,
       "users"."allow_twitter_sync"                  AS t0_r47,
       "users"."allow_facebook_sync"                 AS t0_r48,
       "users"."head_coach"                          AS t0_r49,
       "users"."head_coach_email"                    AS t0_r50,
       "users"."has_recruited_others"                AS t0_r51,
       "users"."customer_id"                         AS t0_r52,
       "users"."last_4_digits"                       AS t0_r53,
       "users"."removed_from_listing"                AS t0_r54,
       "users"."slug"                                AS t0_r55,
       "users"."college_minor"                       AS t0_r56,
       "users"."type"                                AS t0_r57,
       "users"."billing_expiration_month"            AS t0_r58,
       "users"."billing_expiration_year"             AS t0_r59,
       "users"."billing_name"                        AS t0_r60,
       "users"."billing_address"                     AS t0_r61,
       "users"."billing_city"                        AS t0_r62,
       "users"."billing_state"                       AS t0_r63,
       "users"."billing_zip"                         AS t0_r64,
       "users"."college_id"                          AS t0_r65,
       "users"."agreed_to_age_requirements"          AS t0_r66,
       "users"."primary_sport_primary_position_id"   AS t0_r67,
       "users"."secondary_sport_primary_position_id" AS t0_r68,
       "users"."recruit_status_id"                   AS t0_r69,
       "users"."active_flag"                         AS t0_r70,
       "users"."public"                              AS t0_r71,
       "invitations"."id"                            AS t1_r0,
       "invitations"."sender_id"                     AS t1_r1,
       "invitations"."role_id"                       AS t1_r2,
       "invitations"."to"                            AS t1_r3,
       "invitations"."accepted_at"                   AS t1_r4,
       "invitations"."token"                         AS t1_r5,
       "invitations"."created_at"                    AS t1_r6,
       "invitations"."updated_at"                    AS t1_r7,
       "invitations"."current_state"                 AS t1_r8,
       "invitations"."requester_id"                  AS t1_r9,
       "invitations"."user_type"                     AS t1_r10,
       "invitations"."type"                          AS t1_r11
FROM   "users"
       INNER JOIN "stats"
               ON "stats"."athlete_id" = "users"."id"
       LEFT OUTER JOIN "invitations"
                    ON "invitations"."requester_id" = "users"."id"
WHERE  "users"."removed_from_listing" = 'f'
       AND "users"."type" IN ( 'Athlete' )
       AND (( "invitations"."current_state" IN ( 'accepted' )
               OR "invitations"."current_state" IS NULL ))
       AND ( users.primary_sport_id = 13
              OR users.secondary_sport_id = 13 )
       AND (( "stats"."stat_type_id" = 22
              AND "stats"."value" > '2.0' ))
```

The result is an Athlete.

Call 2 (two parameters):

The second call however, returns [], but should be the same athlete...

```
SELECT "users"."id"                                  AS t0_r0,
       "users"."name"                                AS t0_r1,
       "users"."first_name"                          AS t0_r2,
       "users"."last_name"                           AS t0_r3,
       "users"."facebook_id"                         AS t0_r4,
       "users"."access_token"                        AS t0_r5,
       "users"."birthday"                            AS t0_r6,
       "users"."gender"                              AS t0_r7,
       "users"."device_token"                        AS t0_r8,
       "users"."current_city"                        AS t0_r9,
       "users"."hometown"                            AS t0_r10,
       "users"."relationship_status"                 AS t0_r11,
       "users"."avatar_file_name"                    AS t0_r12,
       "users"."avatar_content_type"                 AS t0_r13,
       "users"."avatar_file_size"                    AS t0_r14,
       "users"."avatar_updated_at"                   AS t0_r15,
       "users"."email"                               AS t0_r16,
       "users"."encrypted_password"                  AS t0_r17,
       "users"."reset_password_token"                AS t0_r18,
       "users"."reset_password_sent_at"              AS t0_r19,
       "users"."remember_created_at"                 AS t0_r20,
       "users"."sign_in_count"                       AS t0_r21,
       "users"."current_sign_in_at"                  AS t0_r22,
       "users"."last_sign_in_at"                     AS t0_r23,
       "users"."current_sign_in_ip"                  AS t0_r24,
       "users"."last_sign_in_ip"                     AS t0_r25,
       "users"."authentication_token"                AS t0_r26,
       "users"."created_at"                          AS t0_r27,
       "users"."updated_at"                          AS t0_r28,
       "users"."time_zone"                           AS t0_r29,
       "users"."username"                            AS t0_r30,
       "users"."middle_name"                         AS t0_r31,
       "users"."primary_sport_id"                    AS t0_r32,
       "users"."state"                               AS t0_r33,
       "users"."high_school"                         AS t0_r34,
       "users"."phone"                               AS t0_r35,
       "users"."user_type_id"                        AS t0_r36,
       "users"."agreed_to_terms_and_conditions"      AS t0_r37,
       "users"."agreed_to_information_integrity"     AS t0_r38,
       "users"."agreed_to_content_responsibility"    AS t0_r39,
       "users"."account_type_id"                     AS t0_r40,
       "users"."social_score"                        AS t0_r41,
       "users"."recruit_year"                        AS t0_r42,
       "users"."college_major"                       AS t0_r43,
       "users"."secondary_sport_id"                  AS t0_r44,
       "users"."handedness"                          AS t0_r45,
       "users"."checkdin_id"                         AS t0_r46,
       "users"."allow_twitter_sync"                  AS t0_r47,
       "users"."allow_facebook_sync"                 AS t0_r48,
       "users"."head_coach"                          AS t0_r49,
       "users"."head_coach_email"                    AS t0_r50,
       "users"."has_recruited_others"                AS t0_r51,
       "users"."customer_id"                         AS t0_r52,
       "users"."last_4_digits"                       AS t0_r53,
       "users"."removed_from_listing"                AS t0_r54,
       "users"."slug"                                AS t0_r55,
       "users"."college_minor"                       AS t0_r56,
       "users"."type"                                AS t0_r57,
       "users"."billing_expiration_month"            AS t0_r58,
       "users"."billing_expiration_year"             AS t0_r59,
       "users"."billing_name"                        AS t0_r60,
       "users"."billing_address"                     AS t0_r61,
       "users"."billing_city"                        AS t0_r62,
       "users"."billing_state"                       AS t0_r63,
       "users"."billing_zip"                         AS t0_r64,
       "users"."college_id"                          AS t0_r65,
       "users"."agreed_to_age_requirements"          AS t0_r66,
       "users"."primary_sport_primary_position_id"   AS t0_r67,
       "users"."secondary_sport_primary_position_id" AS t0_r68,
       "users"."recruit_status_id"                   AS t0_r69,
       "users"."active_flag"                         AS t0_r70,
       "users"."public"                              AS t0_r71,
       "invitations"."id"                            AS t1_r0,
       "invitations"."sender_id"                     AS t1_r1,
       "invitations"."role_id"                       AS t1_r2,
       "invitations"."to"                            AS t1_r3,
       "invitations"."accepted_at"                   AS t1_r4,
       "invitations"."token"                         AS t1_r5,
       "invitations"."created_at"                    AS t1_r6,
       "invitations"."updated_at"                    AS t1_r7,
       "invitations"."current_state"                 AS t1_r8,
       "invitations"."requester_id"                  AS t1_r9,
       "invitations"."user_type"                     AS t1_r10,
       "invitations"."type"                          AS t1_r11
FROM   "users"
       INNER JOIN "stats"
               ON "stats"."athlete_id" = "users"."id"
       LEFT OUTER JOIN "invitations"
                    ON "invitations"."requester_id" = "users"."id"
WHERE  "users"."removed_from_listing" = 'f'
       AND "users"."type" IN ( 'Athlete' )
       AND (( "invitations"."current_state" IN ( 'accepted' )
               OR "invitations"."current_state" IS NULL ))
       AND ( users.primary_sport_id = 13
              OR users.secondary_sport_id = 13 )
       AND (( "stats"."stat_type_id" = 22
              AND "stats"."value" > '2.0' ))
       AND (( "stats"."stat_type_id" = 2
              AND "stats"."value" > '10' ))
```

Any idea why this isn't working? Bumfuddled!

:::::UPDATE::::: 
Fixed it by doing the following, and its still pretty fast:

```
def query
athletes = Athlete.listed.for_sport( self.sport )
relation = athletes

return relation if @conditions.blank?

@conditions = @conditions.map { |k, v| v } if @conditions.is_a?(Hash)

@conditions.each do |condition|
  case condition[:type]
  when "stat"
    if !condition[:q].eql?("")
      relation = case condition[:predicate]
      when /less than/i
        athletes.joins{stats}.where{(stats.stat_type_id.eq condition[:stat_type_id]) & (stats.value.lt (StatType.where(:id => condition[:stat_type_id]).first.display_as_decimal == true ? condition[:q].to_f.to_s : condition[:q].to_i.to_s))}
      when /greater than/i
        athletes.joins{stats}.where{(stats.stat_type_id.eq condition[:stat_type_id]) & (stats.value.gt (StatType.where(:id => condition[:stat_type_id]).first.display_as_decimal == true ? condition[:q].to_f.to_s : condition[:q].to_i.to_s))}
      when /equal to/i
        athletes.joins{stats}.where{(stats.stat_type_id.eq condition[:stat_type_id]) & (stats.value.eq (StatType.where(:id => condition[:stat_type_id]).first.display_as_decimal == true ? condition[:q].to_f.to_s : condition[:q].to_i.to_s))}
      when /not equal to/i
        athletes.joins{stats}.where{(stats.stat_type_id.eq condition[:stat_type_id]) & (stats.value.not_eq (StatType.where(:id => condition[:stat_type_id]).first.display_as_decimal == true ? condition[:q].to_f.to_s : condition[:q].to_i.to_s))}
      end
    end
  when "academic"
    relation
  when "social"
    relation
  end
end

relation
end
```

Comment: Those rendered queries are really too long to read. They need better formatting.

Comment: I think a mod formatted it for me, thanks a lot! I was having issues doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second query has a WHERE clause that ends like this:

```
 AND (( "stats"."stat_type_id" = 22
              AND "stats"."value" > '2.0' ))
 AND (( "stats"."stat_type_id" = 2
              AND "stats"."value" > '10' ))
```

`stat_type_id` can't be equal to 2 and 22 at the same time. You'll need a second join to stats table like:

```
INNER JOIN "stats"
               ON "stats"."athlete_id" = "users"."id"
INNER JOIN "stats" AS s2
               ON "s2"."athlete_id" = "users"."id"
(...)
AND (( "stats"."stat_type_id" = 22
              AND "stats"."value" > '2.0' ))
AND (( "s2"."stat_type_id" = 2
              AND "s2"."value" > '10' ))
```

If you don't want to do joins dynamicaly the alternative is a subquery like:

```
SELECT athlete_id
 FROM stats
 WHERE
 ( "stats"."stat_type_id" = 22
              AND "stats"."value" > '2.0' )
OR ( "s2"."stat_type_id" = 2
              AND "s2"."value" > '10' )
GROUP BY athlete_id
HAVING COUNT(*)=<the number of parameters you want to filter by>
```

This will return all athletes that meet the criteria so join that with the rest of your tables.

Comment: Hmm, I understand the issue @Jakub Kania, I'm just unsure of what I'd have to do in my loop for that to work. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Keep in mind, it still needs to function in such a way that BOTH filters must be true for the athlete to be returned, it shouldn't return all athletes where filter 1 is true and all athletes where filter 2 is true

Comment: @Robokid Joining to the same table twice is the way. It could also be done with a subquery but that would be overcomplicating.

Comment: looking at my code, I'm unsure of how to do this still. The problem I'm running into is my page allows for (technically) infinite filters, as much as the user wants to add (via an add filter button), so the loop isn't just two times through, it needs to be able to join as many times as necessary without having this issue.

Comment: @Robokid I updated with the subquery solutions, could be easy for you this way.

Comment: thank you very much. My problem is trying to rewrite the above in Squeel, because it doesn't have a way to alias or anything.